# Error while performing authentication using firebase with flutter. [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Exception: PlatformException

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, exception, configuration

I am using firebase with flutter to perform authentication. I have configured firebase using firebase cli.

Now when I am running the app I am receiving the exception [image]

Further when i navigate to the registration page it gives the following error:
[image]

Following is the code for

**main.dart**

```
void main()  {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // Ensure that Flutter is initialized before calling Firebase.initializeApp()
   Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(FlashChat());
}
```

**registration.dart**

```
  @override
  _RegistrationScreenState createState() => _RegistrationScreenState();
}

class _RegistrationScreenState extends State<RegistrationScreen> {
  late String email;
  late String password;
  final auth =FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
}
```

**android/buil.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**
app/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.flutter_chat"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_chat"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Firebase.initializeApp`'s return type is a Future
so if you want to wait Future type object finished, you must set `await` keyword in front of `Firebase.initializeApp`.

and if you want to use `await` keyword in Flutter, you must set `async` keyword in front of main function

your code's problem is flutter construct widget tree by runApp(), before does not resolved Future object, Future. so Program does not find FirebaseApp instance that time.

so You should just modify your code to this.

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```